# Progress indicator with shared variables

Tags: programming, dynamic, parallelization, monitoring

I'm trying to create a custom progress indicator for a parallelized computation, using `Dynamic` and `SetSharedVariables` to display and update the progress indicator during the calculation. Two questions:

1. **What is the best way to allow parallel kernels to update the progress?** Should I have a function which accepts a `Dynamic[x_]` argument and do something like this?

   ```
   Monitor[PerformCalculations[Dynamic[progress]],
     ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[progress]]];
   (* or this: *)
   ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[progress]]
   PerformCalculations[Dynamic[progress]]

   (* note: 'progress' here will be a list or some other custom structure 
      for indicating various aspects of the progress of each kernel *)

   PerformCalculations[Dynamic[progress_]] := Module[{calc, ...},
       SetSharedVariable[progress];
       calc[stuff_] := Module[{...},
         ...;
         (* how does this part work? *) UpdateProgress[Dynamic[progress]];
        ];
       ParallelMap[calc, data];
     ];
   ```
2. **How do I avoid race conditions of shared variables?** A quick test indicates that shared variables have some caveats when running with parallel kernels:

   [image]

   I would have expected the `test = Append[test, ...]` expression to be evaluated atomically so that each kernel would build on the results of the kernels that had already executed. However it seems like the kernels read the value of `test` before writing it, so there is a race condition that causes the final value to be simply `{8}`. What is the best way to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 9):

I have my own progress indicator function in my toolbag. That has this form:

```
progressBar[dyn_, total_] :=
  Print@Row[
    { ProgressIndicator[dyn, {0, total}], " "
    , Dynamic@NumberForm[100. dyn/total, {\[Infinity], 2}]
    , "% ", dyn
    }
  ]
```

I use it in this way:

```
testFunction[data_]:=Module[{i=1,len=Length[data]},
    SetSharedVariable[i];
    progressBar[Dynamic@i,len];
    ParallelMap[(i++;Pause[0.1];#)&,data]
]
```

Now let's call the `testFunction` over the list `Range[100]`

```
testFunction[Range[100]]
```

[image: progress indicator]

So with these two steeps (`SetSharedVariable[i];progressBar[Dynamic@i,len];`) and with the progress indicator function (`progressBar`), it's very easy to implement it. It's the way I do.

### Tip

Sometimes to work with shared variables, it's important to use `SetSharedFunction`, and [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39811/2266) explain how to use it.